# Support for ICE40UP5K-SG48I?

Tags: fpga, yosys, icestorm

I asked this question .. and got no answers and down voted

> The IceStorm website shows support for,
>
> iCE40-UP5K-**UWG30**
>
> The Single Wire Aggregation Demo / Development Board  from Lattice
> uses a Different part (package diff only?),
>
> ICE40UP5K-**SG48I**
>
> Will IceStorm work with this part given appropriate  changes to pin
> constraints?

Well, I thought this might be an easy albeit dumb question.

So, I guess I should re-pose the question ..

I'm rusty at FPGA's .. haven't done then for years ..

I did research first but I didn't include it as I
thought the question was pretty basic.

- I looked for projects using IceStorm with the UP-5k
  and found none.
- I checked the ICEStorm site and found

> Support for all package variants of LP1K, LP4K, LP8K and HX1K, HX4K, and HX8K.

The 5K is sadly missing .. This might be the answer to my question
but I wasn't sure if the was dated.

- So I installed **nextpr** and ran,

> ./nextpnr-ice40 --up5k --package sg48

yielding,

> Info: Program finished normally.

Which implies that the ICE40UP5K-SG48I
will work ..

- Then for fun I ran,

> locate -i sg48

to hopefully find more information and got,

> icestorm/icefuzz/pinloc/pinloc-u4k-sg48.sh

So, does this imply it's only for the u4k and not for the u5k .. ?

Now I'm even more confused ..

I'm hoping to get an answer to the question
to save myself a week which might end in a dry hole ..

Tom

Comment: This was downvoted because this is the WRONG FORUM.  StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks very much Tim ... The IceStorm  site suggested I post here with the 'yosys'tag for help. I added the "icestorm" and "fpga" tag .. Was that an error. This is only my second post to stackoverflow. I guess I don't know the 'ropes' yet ..

Comment: You might try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the icestorm toolchain supports the iCE40-UP5K-SG48 device.

From the supported devices list on the [icestrom website](https://clifford.at/icestorm):

| Part | Package | Pin Spacing | I/Os | nextpnr opts | arachne-pnr opts | icetime opts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iCE40-UP5K-SG48 | 48-pin QFN (7 x 7 mm) | 0.50 mm | 39 | `-up5k –package sg48` | `-d 5k -P sg48` | `-d up5k` |

Furthermore, this device is soldered onto the [iCEBreaker FPGA Board](https://docs.icebreaker-fpga.org/hardware/icebreaker/). Thus, the [iCEBreaker examples](https://github.com/icebreaker-fpga/icebreaker-verilog-examples/tree/main/icebreaker)  might be a useful reference for constraint files and tool scripts.